# Do ideals with the same saturation have the same Hilbert polynomial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Suppose $I$ and $J$ are homogeneous ideals in $k[x_0,\dots, x_n]$ (with the usual grading) that have the same saturation with respect to the irrelevant ideal. Do they have the same Hilbert polynomial?

This seems like an elementary question, but I could not find a reference. (Hartshorne exercise II.5.10 has some background information but doesn't answer this question.) Certainly when $I$ is some saturated ideal and $J$ is $I$ with elements of grading $N$ or below removed, the saturation of $J$ is equal to $I$ and they have the same Hilbert function for large $n$, so they have the same Hilbert polynomial.

My motivation for asking this is practical. For example, suppose I am doing computations in a computer algebra system and intersect a bunch of varieties. Will I always need to take the saturation of the ideal defining the intersection before computing the Hilbert polynomial to get the right information about the intersection, or can I just compute the Hilbert polynomial straight away with no preliminary "cleaning"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes. In fact, $I$ and $I_{sat}$ have the same elements for all gradings $n>N$ for some fixed $N$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1037249/284566).